# Access sql query between date range with local date notation

Tags: sql, ms-access

I tried to open a RecordSet in Access with the following query but I get a syntax error every time.

```
SELECT  FromDate
        , UntilDate
        , NotificationText
        ,NotificationDetail 
FROM    ChangeNotification 
WHERE   FromDate <= #" & Date & "# AND 
        UntilDate >=#" & Date & "#"
```

The Date notation is in `22.11.2018` because apparently it's localized and I didn't find a way to undo it.

Do you know a way to execute the query anyway?

Thanks alot

Comment: Syntax error where? Inside your query or your vba code?

Comment: Just thinking out loud - could it be a problem with `Date` as it's a reserved word or are you using `Date` to return the current date and only records from the current date?

Comment: The date should be in US format in SQL.  Try passing the date through the [SQLDate](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html) procedure (item 2 in the link).

Comment: Please describe the data types of *FromDate* and *UntilDate* as that is an unusual date notation.

Comment: @SalmanA it says "Syntax error in date in query expression 'FromDate <= #13.11.2018# AND UntilDate >=#13.11.2018'"

Comment: @Parfait UntilDate & FromDate are of Data Type Date/Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Date` is the same named VBA procedure then you could use just this:

```
SELECT FromDate, UntilDate, NotificationText, NotificationDetail FROM ChangeNotification WHERE FromDate <= Date() AND UntilDate >= Date()
```

Also I presume that the fields `FromDate` and `UntilDate` in the table are of datatype `Date/Time`.

Comment: This is it, just using the Sql Date function instead of vba